# Keeping the previous value of an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following situation: If the **name** attribute of my **student** object changes, I want to keep the old value and save it to another table.

So, If I have a student object with the name attribute 'John 1', after a **student.update_attributes(:name => 'John 2')** I want to be able to capture the old name value 'John 1' in a **before_update** callback hook, for instance. What's the best way to do that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `before_update` hook, you can access special `_was` methods to get the previous value of each field

```
before_update do
  new_name = self.name     # 'John 2'
  old_name = self.name_was # 'John 1'
end
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty awesome. Tomorrow I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Heres the APIdock for ActiveRecord::Dirty, for future references: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty